# Stuck on Sliding between two activities

Tags: java, android, adapter, pager

I stuck with the project trying to make Page Slider between two activities.

- All I know that each activity independently works, but when I try to set up PageAdapter for sliding putting:
- **Also, I write activity in Manifest, initialize all variables from XML in Java, but the problem starts exactly at the moment when I set up onClickListener for my buttons.**

  LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
      List pages = new ArrayList();

  ```
  View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo, null);
  pages.add(page);
  page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cameragrid, null);
  pages.add(page);

  CameraPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new CameraPagerAdapter(pages);
  ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
  viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
  viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);    //view being shown firstly

  setContentView(viewPager);
  ```

  instead of `*setContentView(R.layout.photo);*` it's doesn't launch.
  What did I missed? Thanks for advance.

First Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    makeAdditionalPageSlide(); //>>> problems started here

    initialize();

    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.dinam);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
}
public void makeAdditionalPageSlide(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    List<View> pages = new ArrayList<View>();

    View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo, null);
    pages.add(page);
    page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cameragrid, null);
    pages.add(page);

    CameraPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new CameraPagerAdapter(pages);
    ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);    //view being shown firstly

    setContentView(viewPager); 


}

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.ivReturnedPic);
    ib = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.ibTakePic);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSetWall);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    ib.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.bSetWall:
        try {
            getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bmp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    case R.id.ibTakePic:
        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
    break;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
```

PageAdapter:

```
public class CameraPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter  {
 List<View> pages = null;

    public CameraPagerAdapter(List<View> pages){
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position){
        View v = pages.get(position);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v, 0);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view){
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return pages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object){
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View arg0){
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1){
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState(){
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View arg0){
    }
```

}
the second Activity:

```
public class CameraGrid extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cameragrid);
    GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.cameragrid);
    CameraImageAdapter ia = new CameraImageAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    gv.setAdapter(ia);
    //gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this); 
    gv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View iv, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CameraImageDetails.class);
    i.putExtra("id", position);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

}

Comment: where did u put first block of code?! which class?

Comment: I put first block of code in my First Actvity. in a method **makeAdditionalPageSlide**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to make mainActivity.xml layout with placeholder for ViewPager and setContentView(R.layout.mainActivity)

Things related to content of page view u setup in PageViewAdapter.

Maybe I didn't quite understand logic u tried to do it, but it seems a bit confusing.. :S